# Planning for your own robot arm

Tags: ros, urdf, pr2-arm-navigation, move-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Anyone got a simple way or easy to understand tutorials for planning for your own robot? Can't seem to understand the OMPL tutorials on ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12850/planning-for-your-own-robot-arm/) by [OptiX](https://answers.ros.org/users/1535/optix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Oh, I thought OMPL is just the library used in `arm_navigation` and is not to be used directly.

Have you seen the enclosing [arm_navigation stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation arm_navigation) (with its arm_navigation_experimental sibling) at a whole? There are tutorials to get it running. You will need a simple [URDF robot model](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf) for the kinematics, but it's not that complex and there are tutorials, too.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1